# R mutating multiple columns with the same number

Tags: r, dplyr

let's say I have three columns: columnA, columnB, columnC,

and I would like to mutate each of the three columns. problem is if I do something like

```
mutate(columnA = columnA + runif(1, (-1/70), (1/70) ),
       columnB = columnB + runif(1, (-1/70), (1/70) ),
       columnC = columnC + runif(1, (-1/70), (1/70) )
```

Problem is I want the same generated number for all three columns but the above will create 3 different generated numbers.
Does anyone know how I can apply the same runif to all columns needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `noise` column firstly, add to columns `A,B,C` and then drop it:

```
mutate(noise = runif(1, (-1/70), (1/70)),
       columnA = columnA + noise,
       columnB = columnB + noise,
       columnC = columnC + noise) %>% select(-noise)
```

---

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(2,3,4))
df %>% 
    mutate(noise = runif(1, (-1/70), (1/70)), 
           A = A + noise, B = B+ noise) %>% 
    select(-noise)

#         A        B
#1 1.003914 2.003914
#2 2.003914 3.003914
#3 3.003914 4.003914
```

Comment: `noise` doesn't need to go in the data frame. Create a new variable.

Comment: @Spacedman A new variable definitely works if OP doesn't want to stick to pipes `%>%`.

Comment: Creating a new column like that is a bad idea - suppose the data already has a column called "noise", you've just stomped on it.

Comment: @Spacedman I wonder how much chance a meaningful column can be named as `noise`; And if there is really a column named `noise`, we can name the variable as something crazier here, maybe `noise__` or `temp`. This is just a demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, faster and possibly cleaner base R version:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(2,3,4))
```

and in a functional form for piping and reuse, also cleans up the temporary `noise` vector:

```
modab = function(df){
  noise = runif(1,-1/70,1/70)
  df$A = df$A + noise
  df$B = df$B + noise
  df
}
```

Comment: Or there's `df[] <- lapply(df, \`+\`, runif(1,-1/70,1/70))`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, just create a variable and add it to your data.

```
r <- runif(1, -1/70, 1/70)
mutate_all(df, function(x) x + r)
```